# Why create database database statement returns more than one value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have following database statement:
(and files, access and everything is ready for executing this statement)

```
CREATE DATABASE [test1] ON 
    (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\test1.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\test1_log.ldf') 
FOR ATTACH
```

And when I do it via `c#` it returns me more than one value.

```
public void RunQuery(string query, bool longRunning = false)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = longRunning ? _longRunningCommandTimeout : _commandTimeout;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

```
Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The database is actually attached despite of returning this error.

And it's really weird. Because usually it's just a message.
And moreover when I execute the same query(under the same user) via `MSSMS` it gets me just the following:

```
Commands completed successfully.
```

Is it possible that `create database` statement returns more than one result ?

Comment: `And when I do it via c# it returns me more than one value.` <= How are you running it in c#? Can you share that (preferably minimal) code?

Comment: @Igor yes, sure. just added

Comment: The likely cause is a bug in a server-level DDL trigger. Please to not [multi-post the  same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231444/why-create-database-database-statement-returns-more-than-one-value) as it causes  duplicate effort for all parties involved.

Comment: @Igor, BTW, the   "Commands completed successfully." message is not a result returned by SQL Server. Its  a message displayed by SSMS.

Comment: @Igor, you said "via MSMS it gets me just single result." so I just wanted to make sure you understood that was neither a message or result returned by SQL Server, just a message displayed by the SSMS application. Your C#  code  will not get that message.

Comment: @DanGuzman - Igor isn't the OP. :-)

Comment: DOH. Sorry @Igor. Picked the wrong user.

Comment: ok. I agree it's just a message. not a result. but anyway why i got the following: `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` ?

Comment: Can you please post the query in the question.

Comment: @KieranDevlin it's actually already there since that moment when i posted the question

Comment: @isxaker it's not. You have a query that you say you run, and C# code that *doesn't* show how the `query` parameter is set or where it gets its value from. Post something that can actually be used to reproduce the issue

Comment: @isxaker the error itself complains about expressions that don't exist in the query you posted. It actually complains about a *subquery*. So either `query` is not what you thought it is, or some server-level trigger executed invalid code. Which Dan Guzman already explained.

Comment: @isxaker in fact, this query belongs in dba.stackexchange.com. As I see though, you already posted there, you already got asnwers explaining that you can't get that error from *this* query unless there are server triggers involved. The commenters there are some of the best known SQL Server authors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yea, thanks. I got a direction that might be right. I mean s-level triggers. so now I'm gonna use the following statement - `DISABLE Trigger ALL ON ALL SERVER;`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually my question contains query. `create database ...` Can you see it ?

Comment: @isxaker the error complains about a *subquery*. There's no subquery in what you posted. That menas that either a *different* query was executed or there's a trigger. That's why people tell you to post the actual code that executes this query.

Comment: @isxaker now if you say you execute the same thing in SSMS and it works, it means that the `query` parameter *doesn't* contain the query you think

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have no idea what is it. I just have this code and that's all. So that's why i asked that question.

Comment: Debug your code and check what `query` contains. Or use SQL Server Profiler, or Extended Events to see what's actually being sent to SQL Server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fair enough. but that's all what i have. so any idea how i can get the real query ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's already from debug.

Comment: Did you try *debugging your code*? Did you try using SQL Server Profiler? You can do both

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I usually debug my code. Thanks for idea try to use Sql Server Profiler.